# How to check the robustness of a null result of an lmer() model using a Bayesian analysis?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, prior

I have an lmer() model that has a theoretically important null result. I would like to use a Bayesian analysis to check the robustness of this null result.

What is the best way to do this?

I had assumed that computing a Bayes Factor would be the way to go, but it seems that this value varies widely depending on the prior. I don't have a good way to choose a prior. Do you have a suggestion for how I can check the robustness of the null result? Is there:

1. A generally accepted prior I can use?
2. An automated way to compute Bayes Factors at different values of the prior?

Edit: I am adding some additional details of my model. It is a linear mixed effects model of an experiment in which participants made responses to words. There are random effects for both words and subject. There are several fixed effects in the model: five continuous variables and one dichotomous predictor. This dichotomous predictor is the one with the important null result. I'd like a way to quantify the robustness of this null result. I don't have a good way to choose an informed prior.

Comment: How much data do you have?  With enough data, the priors become less important (as I'm sure you know).  Also, I think Gelman wrote on default priors [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf) though I haven't read the paper in a long time and am not confident it is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thanks! I have used that Gelman paper in the past, but I found the scaling to be a bit cumbersome. But maybe that is unavoidable?

Comment: can you give us some more information on your problem?  Its a bit nebulous as of now and I'm afraid all anyone could do is just give very general advice.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Sure! I added details in the edit.